# Send csv value as an array to mongo db (compass)

Tags: arrays, mongodb, compass

Im trying to send through mongo compass a value from a csv to a new database. The problem is that the value is a sttring composed with multiple words. Is there a way to send it as an array?

The string is: pop uk, pop

Mongo compass sends it as Genres: "pop uk, pop"
What I need is Genres: ["pop uk", "pop"]

Answer (score 0):

Use split() method on the csv string and split by ','- it will return an array of substrings

Here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split